# Does an AWS RDS Endpoint FQDN change when making an instance Private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS, accessed by some servers in AWS EC2, all connected to the same VPC.

One AWS RDS instance we have apparently was set to "Publicly Accessible", and we want to correct this.

My question: If I change the Instance's settings from "Publicly Accessible: Yes" to "Publicly Accessible: No", will that change the Endpoint FQDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't change the endpoint. Of course you should take a manual snapshot just in case something goes wrong, so you can restore. Manual snapshots are never deleted by AWS.

The great thing about AWS is things are so cheap you can try them yourself. Create yourself a t2.micro RDS instance that's publicly accessible, get it going. Copy the FQDN. Now make the change you're planning, and check the FQDN again. Total time: 10 minutes. Total cost, $0.10.

You can also set your security groups / Network ACLs to close the port externally, then it won't be publicly accessible. I have an RDS instance that is deliberately publicly accessible, I just changed my security group to remove my home IP, and I could no longer log into the database.